# generics and wild cards

Tags: java, generics, interface

I'm trying to write

```
public static Comparable<? extends Comparable>  getMax (ArrayList <? extends Comparable> list)
```

and I recieve an exception

> - Comparable is a raw type. References to generic type Comparable should be 
>      parameterized

what can I do? I want recieve a collection and return an varaiable who implement the interface

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the max value in a list, why do you return a `Comparable`? Returning `T` where `T` is the type of object that the list stores is much better.

In addition, wildcards should not be used here. If you write your method like this:

```
public static Comparable<? extends Comparable>  getMax (ArrayList <? extends Comparable> list)
```

then the client code can pass `ArrayList<Integer>` and you can return a `String` which makes no sense at all.

To avoid that kind of situation, I suggest you to use a generic type `T`

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T getMax (ArrayList<T> list) {
    return list.stream().max(Comparable::compareTo).orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: to be most general use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`